# Getting a "display" bounding box for a clipped object

Tags: svg

I need to find the visible x and y bounds of an object which has been clipped, so that I can place other objects around it. However, the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#clipPath-geometry) states that `getBBox` doesn't take into account clip paths, so I can't use the bounding box. Any idea how can I can find the display limits for a clipped object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a hidden `<use>` element that references the path in the clipPath and get the bounding box of that. Then you just want the intersection of the bounding box of your object and the use object.

```
<defs>
  <clipPath id="clipPath">
    <path id="path" ...>
  </clipPath>
</defs>

<use id="clipPathBounds" visibility="hidden" xlink:href="#path"/>
```

Comment: I was hoping to find something a bit more lateral than this; calculating an intersection is, in general, difficult. I found a long exchange on the SVG list about this a couple of days ago, but unfortunately I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: Calculating the intersection of two rectangles is easy.

    result.x = max(x, aRect.x);
    result.y = max(y, aRect.y);
    result.width = min(XMost(), aRect.XMost()) - result.x;
    result.height = min(YMost(), aRect.YMost()) - result.y;
    if (result.width < 0 || result.height < 0) {
      didn't intersect at all
    }

Where XMost() = rect.x + rect.height etc

Comment: True, but a clip path can be completely general. Try computing the intersection of an arbitrary Bezier with anything else. Even if you only want a rectangular result, as I do, then it's non-trivial. It has to be done by the renderer in general, to sort out the pixel-level detail, but SVG doesn't appear to define any way to do this.

Comment: That's what the <use> trick is for in the answer, to convert the arbitrary path data for a rectangle.

Comment: Ahh.. sorry, completely misunderstood you. Looks good - thanks.

Comment: Does this solution also apply when the object clipped has been transformed (e.g. translated, rotated)?